# Is there a better way to initialize an array?

Tags: c++

Given an array map with size of 256, what is the best way to initialize it so that each element is false?

```
bool map[256];

for (int i=0; i<256; i++)
{
    map[i] = false;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
bool map[256] = { false };
```

edit: for a reference to the standard as to why this is legal, see the answers below.

Comment: Hello Idan, This is a C++ standard way to initialize all elements in an array? -- thank you

Comment: yes, it is defined in the standard (trying to look it up as we speak)

Comment: I've looked it up, if you're still looking. See my answer for the paragraph number(s).

Answer (score 15):

```
bool map[256] = {false};
```

(C++ also allows `bool map[256] = {};`. The above works in C too.)

This will set `map[0]` to `false`, and "default-initialize" the rest of 255 members (C++98 §8.5.1/7: "If there are fewer *initializers* in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be default-initialized"; C99 §6.7.8/21).

For `bool`, "default-initialize" means set to `(bool)0`, i.e. `false` (C++98 §8.5/5; C99 §6.7.8/10).

Note that this method doesn't work if you want to initialize to `true`.

Comment: Just to mention, this is only valid for C++ but not for C.

Comment: Hello Als, thank you for reminder me that C doesn't have bool type.

Comment: @q0987: C has had a boolean type for 11 years now. For example C# didn't exist 11 years ago.

Comment: @KennyTM: I think value initialization was added in TC1/C++03, and in that standard the additional members are value-initialized, not default-initialized. Not that it makes any difference in this case. If you know of a compiler that implements C++98 but not C++03, please take it out and shoot it ;-)

Comment: @Als This form of initialization is available in C99.
@q0987 The bool type is available in C99 by using the <stdbool.h> header.

Comment: @Marc,eq,q0987: That was my bad, I was under the impression that it is valid only in C++. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that it will not work correctly for `true`.

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
bool map[256] = { 0 };
```

Some would say this:

```
bool map[256] = {};
```

But to me that just looks a little weird.

Why use "0" rather than "false"? It's not a big deal, but I do it because the array initializer is in effect padded out to the size of the array *with 0*, not with copies of the first element. Since the initialization of elements 1 through 255 is defined in terms of the value "0" (which of course converts to `false`), I see no harm in element 0 being initialized with "0" too. Having a "0" at the end of a too-short initializer list for scalar types reminds me of what's really going on.

Specifically, the standard defines this at 8.5.1/7 (initializer list shorter than array), and 8.5/5 (value-initializing a `bool` is equivalent to initializing it with the value 0 converted to `bool`).

Answer (score 3):

Absent a reason to do otherwise, the best choice is probably to use a vector:

```
std::vector<bool> map(256, false);
```

`vector<bool>`, however, is a specialization that's rather different from what you might expect. Depending on the situation, you might prefer:

```
std::vector<char> map(256, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++, X = { 0 } is an idiomatic universal zero-initializer. This was a feature carried forward from C.

```
bool map[256] = { 0 };
```

Comment: If you want to be really pedantic, in C++ it constructs the first element with `0`, and value-constructs the other elements. For a scalar type like `bool`, this all amounts to zero-initialization (which is why it's just pedantry in this case), but for class types it might be different.